# sqlSave fails when tablename is longer than 18 characters

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I am currently writing a script that downloads a bunch of .csv's from a FTP server, and then puts each .csv in a MySQL database as its own table.

I download the .csv's from the FTP using RCurl and place all of the .csv's in my working directory. To create tables out of each .csv, I am using the sqlSave function from the RODBC package, where the table name is the same name as the .csv. This works fine whenever a .csv name is less than 18 characters, but when it is greater it fails. And by "fails", I mean R crashes. To track down the bug, I called debug on sqlSave.

I found that there are at least two functions that sqlSave calls that cause R to crash. The first is RODBC:::odbcTableExists, which is a non-visible function. Here is the code for the function:

```
 RODBC:::odbcTableExists
function (channel, tablename, abort = TRUE, forQuery = TRUE, 
    allowDot = attr(channel, "interpretDot")) 
{
    if (!odbcValidChannel(channel)) 
        stop("first argument is not an open RODBC channel")
    if (length(tablename) != 1) 
        stop(sQuote(tablename), " should be a name")
    tablename <- as.character(tablename)
    switch(attr(channel, "case"), nochange = {
    }, toupper = tablename <- toupper(tablename), tolower = tablename <- tolower(tablename))
    isExcel <- odbcGetInfo(channel)[1L] == "EXCEL"
    hasDot <- grepl(".", tablename, fixed = TRUE)
    if (allowDot && hasDot) {
        parts <- strsplit(tablename, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
        if (length(parts) > 2) 
            ans <- FALSE
        else {
            res <- if (attr(channel, "isMySQL")) 
                sqlTables(channel, catalog = parts[1], tableName = parts[2])
            else sqlTables(channel, schema = parts[1], tableName = parts[2])
            ans <- is.data.frame(res) && nrow(res) > 0
        }
    }
    else if (!isExcel) {
        res <- sqlTables(channel, tableName = tablename)
        ans <- is.data.frame(res) && nrow(res) > 0
    }
    else {
        res <- sqlTables(channel)
        tables <- stables <- if (is.data.frame(res)) 
            res[, 3]
        else ""
        if (isExcel) {
            tables <- sub("^'(.*)'$", "\\1", tables)
            tables <- unique(c(tables, sub("\\$$", "", tables)))
        }
        ans <- tablename %in% tables
    }
    if (abort && !ans) 
        stop(sQuote(tablename), ": table not found on channel")
    enc <- attr(channel, "encoding")
    if (nchar(enc)) 
        tablename <- iconv(tablename, to = enc)
    if (ans && isExcel) {
        dbname <- if (tablename %in% stables) 
            tablename
        else paste(tablename, "$", sep = "")
        if (forQuery) 
            paste("[", dbname, "]", sep = "")
        else dbname
    }
    else if (ans) {
        if (forQuery && !hasDot) 
            quoteTabNames(channel, tablename)
        else tablename
    }
    else character(0L)
}
```

This fails here when the table name over 18 characters in length:

```
    res <- sqlTables(channel, tableName = tablename)
```

I have fixed it by changing this to:

```
    res <- sqlTables(channel, tablename)
```

I then reassign the function with the same name (odbcTableExists) in the namespace with this code change using assignInNamepace.

RODBC:::odbcTableExists no longer causes an issue. However, R still crashes when sqlwrite is called from within sqlSave(). I called debug on sqlwrite, and I found that RODBC:::odbcColumns (another non-visible function) causes that to crash when tablenames are too long. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to change RODBC:::odbcColumns to avoid the bug like I did before.

I am using R 2.15.1, and the platform is :x86_64-pc-ming32/x64 (64-bit). I should also note that I am trying to run this on a work computer, but if I run the exact same code on my personal computer, R does not crash (no bug). The work computer runs windows 7 professional, and my home computer runs windows 7 home premium with R 2.14.1.

Answer (score 0):

I love this hack (I too have Windows 7 Professional at R 2.15.1 at work), and it does not crash anymore, but it causes another problem after I replaced that line and used assignInNamespace; also for some reason I had to replace odbcValidChannel with RODBC:::odbcValidChannel and quoteTabNames with RODBC:::quoteTabNames

But when I used sqlSave, I got the following error:

Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
  no parameters, so nothing to update

I don't even use odbcUpdate anywhere in the code, and the RODBC::: sqlSave does not have the odbcUpdate call inside.

Any thoughts?

thank you,
-Alex